I need a select query and remove rows by condition with left_join
I have a table Slot and SlotAlteration.
The slot has a time_off_id field.
SlotAlteration has two fields, slot_id and action. Action can be 0 or 1. Each slot can have up to two entries in the SlotAlteration table with action 0 and 1 (not 0 and 0, and not 1 and 1) or have no connections to SlotAdjustment at all.
I need to select all records from the Slot table where time_off_id is null, and if there is no record in SlotAlteration with such slot_id and action 1
So, if time_off_id is null and if there is no row in SlotAdjustment with action 1.
I wrote this query, but it does not work that way i needed.
SELECT * FROM Slot 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SlotAdjustment ON Slot.id = SlotAdjustment.slot_id 
WHERE time_off_id IS null AND (SlotAdjustment.id is null or SlotAdjustment.action = 0);

This is sandbox with example database
https://sqlfiddle.com/postgresql/online-compiler?id=41ee3a0f-0b28-434d-a54c-8b9b8320a0af

Your WHERE clause effectively converts your OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN.  If for the LEFT JOIN  you need to filter on RIGHT table field values, put the condition inside ON.

Does this answer your question? Sql LEFT OUTER JOIN with WHERE clause

You may need to include into the question some examples of records that you would expect to be returned but aren't and records that you would expect not to returned but are. Using EXISTS like SELECT * FROM Slot WHERE time_off_id IS null AND NOT EXISTS (   SELECT * from   where Alterr Slot.id = Alterr.slot_id AND   (Alterr.id is null or action = 0); or SELECT * FROM Slot WHERE time_off_id IS null AND not exists (   SELECT * from   where Alterr Slot.id = Alterr.slot_id AND action <> 1; might be what you want.

What should the expected result be ? Here is a fiddle, if not the solution it might give you a hint

The requirement is a bit unclear. What you need is to get all rows from Slot table where time_off_id is null and the action of the corresponding record in Alterr is not 1?
SELECT * FROM Slot LEFT OUTER JOIN Alterr ON Slot.id = Alterr.slot_id AND Alterr.action != 1
SQLFiddle

Note that tables have columns, not fields.
